# Use FindNext on a Range of Variable Length in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, range, vba

I'm fairly next to excel VBA and am trying to use the FindNext function to find the next non-zero value in a column on the following data set. 
 [image] 

When I first tried to do this I used the Columns function saying: `Columns("J").FindNext().Row` but returned the value of 3 rather than 11. Then I tried tried to use the range object, declaring it as `Range("J2", Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row, "J"))` where Column H has data till the length of Column J. doing this returned the error "Compile Error: Wrong number of Arguments or invalid property assignment" I'm not entirely sure why 1) the compiler wont accept how I declared the Range and 2) why the FindNext function is not returning the row of the next non-zero value. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: you have one too many `)` so: `Range("J2", Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row, "J"))`

Comment: Why don't you just use `.Range("J2").End(xlDown).Row`?

Comment: Does the column contain constants or formulas ??

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for that, so now the error is gone but it still return a value of 3

Comment: @Gary'sStudent no, its all solid values, or no values at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need either *Find()* or *FindNext()* to locate the rows containing non-empties:

```
Sub FindingAnything()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim s As String

    Set rng = Range("J:J").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    For Each r In rng
        s = s & r.Row & vbCrLf
    Next r

    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

[image]

If the column contained some cells with formulas, you would change the *SpecialCells()* argument.  If the column was filled with formulas, some of which return non-Nulls, you would have an interesting problem !

Comment: If that was the case just load the entire column's value into an array and cycle through that.  Just tested it and it was sub 1 second.

Comment: @ScottCraner but how can you do the same thing but one at a time, so the value that is returned would just be 3 rather than all the values

Comment: @vman you would iterate through the array with a standard for loop, and every time the array object was not blank you would do something using the for counter as the row number.